# How can a social button loads article's intro text, instead of site's meta description?

Tags: facebook, joomla1.5

I have install version 1.8 of ITPSocialButtons-Plugin on my Joomla 1.5 site. When a user click on facebook button for example, gets a new tab, that contains article's image, article's title and in my case, site's meta description text. Any idea how can I have article's intro text instead of site's meta description??? Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have discussed this with the developer already.  In my case the problem existed for LinkedIn which is worse because once the article was shared once, you cannot undo it, so everyone shared with the site meta description.

In my case one thing that did help was to copy the intro text into the meta description for the article.  Another thing that helped was to use ITPMeta pro to manage all the tags for each article.

Try at least the article's meta description trick and let me know if that worked for you...if not I think it's time to go back to Todor and ask him to make some changes.

Comment: My friend, **ITPMeta Pro** isn't for Joomla 1.5 so I can't use it. I installed the ["addthis"](https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.UVbq3Ffm7WA) plugin for Joomla 1.5 version, plus two other plugins from "www.perfect-web.co". One for [facebook](http://www.perfect-web.co/joomla/plugins/link-with-article-images-facebook) and one more for [google](http://www.perfect-web.co/joomla/plugins/link-with-article-images-google-plus) sharing and everything is fine now!!!

Comment: I forgot something... You are right about the intro text and meta description. If you left article's meta description empty, it takes site's meta description text!!!

Comment: Aaah yes...Now I remember!  Applogies, I forgot ITPmeta only for 2.5...I think ITPMeta works though, the only difference is that ITPMeta doesn't auto create urls which is not alltogether a bad thing